# Capability to save the flight as *. avi

Tags: c#, directx

we are working on implementing a 3D raster viewer using Microsoft DirectX library. Would like to to know is it possible to save the rotation/spin or flight of the image in directx device as an avi file?

Does DirectX library has this capability?

Regards,
Kishore

Comment: I am sure its possible. Do you know the structure of an avi file, if you don't, then what you want is not possible for you to achieve. At the basic level all a video is images displayed at a certain rate. If you are able to capture 30 frames a second then you should be able to create an avi from those frames.  **What have you tried?**

Comment: You can probably achieve this with the appropiate DirectShow filters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375464(v=vs.85).aspx. Have you had a look at this?